# Mixed Charting DATA sources in the same CHART

Tags: php, javascript, charts, dojo, dojox.charting

I'm new in DOJO and I post here for the first time.
I have a problem to create several lines on the same chart.

I've done a simple test to simulate data and it works

```
  dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");

  makeCharts = function(){
    //crée un nouvel objet graphique
    var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("simplechart");
    chart1.addPlot("line", {type: "Lines"});

    chart1.addPlot("space", {type: "Areas", hAxis: "space x", vAxis: "space y"});
    chart1.addPlot("histo", {type: "Bars", gap: 6, hAxis: "histo x", vAxis: "histo y"});

    chart1.addAxis("histo x", {
      labels: [{value: 1, text: "Jan"}, {value: 2, text: "Feb"},
        {value: 3, text: "Mar"}, {value: 4, text: "Apr"},
        {value: 5, text: "May"}, {value: 6, text: "Jun"},
        {value: 7, text: "Jul"}, {value: 8, text: "Aug"},
        {value: 9, text: "Sep"}, {value: 10, text: "Oct"},
        {value: 11, text: "Nov"}, {value: 12, text: "Dec"}]
    });
    chart1.addAxis("histo y", {vertical: true,
      max: 10,
      stroke: "green",
      fontColor: "black",
      majorTick: {color: "red", length: 6},
      minorTick: {stroke: "black", length: 3}});

    chart1.addSeries("Series 1", [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7],
    {plot:"line", stroke: {color:"red"}});
   chart1.addSeries("Series 2", [1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 6, 4, 5],
   {plot: "space", stroke: {color:"blue"}, fill: "lightblue"});
    chart1.addSeries("Series 3", [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7],
    {plot: "histo", stroke: {color:"green"}, fill: "lightgreen"});

    chart1.render();
```

I Created another php file where I transform my data from Mysql to JSON.
I want now to put the URL of my source to dojo AddSeries.
There will be several sources, differents files sources of data.

I don't know where to put my URL in the code.

Thank you for the help.

---

Thank you for your response.

I've tried this but the "Series 1" doesn't work :

```
      dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");
      dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
      makeCharts = function(){
              test_store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({url: 'data_chart.php'});
        var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("simplechart");
        chart1.addPlot("line", {type: "Lines"});
        chart1.addPlot("space", {type: "Areas", hAxis: "space x", vAxis: "space y"});
        chart1.addPlot("histo", {type: "Bars", gap: 6, hAxis: "histo x", vAxis: "histo"});
        chart1.addAxis("histo x", {
          labels: [{value: 1, text: "Jan"}, {value: 2, text: "Feb"},
            {value: 3, text: "Mar"}, {value: 4, text: "Apr"},
            {value: 5, text: "May"}, {value: 6, text: "Jun"},
            {value: 7, text: "Jul"}, {value: 8, text: "Aug"},
            {value: 9, text: "Sep"}, {value: 10, text: "Oct"},
            {value: 11, text: "Nov"}, {value: 12, text: "Dec"}]});
        chart1.addAxis("histo y", {vertical: true, max: 10, stroke: "green",    fontColor:"black", majorTick: {color: "red", length: 6}, minorTick: {stroke: "black", length: 3}});
        chart1.addSeries("Series 1", {data :test_store,plot:"line", stroke: {color:"red"}});
{color:"black"}});
        chart1.addSeries("Series 2", [1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 6, 4, 5],
        {plot: "space", stroke: {color:"blue"}, fill: "lightblue"});
        chart1.addSeries("Series 3", [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7],
        {plot: "histo", stroke: {color:"green"}, fill: "lightgreen"});
        chart1.render();
```

My data_chart.php is a test : `<?php echo"[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7]"; ?>`

I'm lost, I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would use the [dojox.data.DataChart](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/charting/DataChart.html). 
You have to use a datastore to pass in the data.
See [quickstart-data-usingdatastores](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/data/usingdatastores.html#quickstart-data-usingdatastores) and [dojo.data](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data.html#dojo-data).

First use a [dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#dojo-data-itemfilereadstore). If that works fine, use a composite datastore, that wraps other datastores to get your data from multiple sources (You might have to create that class by yourself)

-- EDIT --

An example using a datachart with an itemfilereadstore:

```
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js.uncompressed.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[ 
        dojo.require("dojox.charting.DataChart");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        url: "stock.json"
    });
    chart = new dojox.charting.DataChart("chartDiv" ,{});
    chart.setStore(store, {symbol:"*"}, "historicPrice");  //  <-- single value property
});
    //]]> 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartDiv" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The content of stock.json:

```
{ "identifier": "symbol", "idAttribute":"symbol", "label": "symbol","items": [
    { "symbol":"ANDT", "name":"Anduct",             "historicPrice":[0.01,3.52,3.66,3.11,3.90,3.11,3.11], "open":3.13,  "price":3.52, "updown":"^",  "change":"+0.39 (+21%)", "low":3.13, "high":3.69 },
    { "symbol":"ATEU", "name":"Ations Europe",      "historicPrice":[6.72,6.76,6.61,6.41,6.31,6.99,7.20], "open":6.72,  "price":6.76, "updown":"^",  "change":"+0.04 (+01%)", "low":6.56, "high":6.77 },
    { "symbol":"BGCN", "name":"Bagies Consulting",  "historicPrice":[4.11,3.98,4.05,4.20,4.16,4.22,3.80], "open":4.11,  "price":3.98, "updown":"v",  "change":"-0.13 (-05%)", "low":3.77, "high":4.11 },
    { "symbol":"BAYC", "name":"BAY Corporation",    "historicPrice":[9.79,9.60,9.50,2.23,9.45,9.76,9.99], "open":9.79,  "price":9.60, "updown":"v",  "change":"-0.19 (+14%)", "low":9.60, "high":9.81 },
    { "symbol":"CRCR", "name":"Corcor PLC",         "historicPrice":[8.44,8.44,8.54,8.60,9.65,8.42,8.44], "open":8.44,  "price":8.44, "updown":"--", "change":"+0.00 (+00%)", "low":8.22, "high":8.44 },
    { "symbol":"DTOA", "name":"Datio PLC",          "historicPrice":[2.11,2.47,3.11,3.06,3.01,3.01,3.00], "open":2.11,  "price":2.47, "updown":"^",  "change":"+0.36 (+36%)", "low":2.11, "high":3.01 }
]}
```

To use multiple stores you need to create a compositeStore that groups multiple stores . Unfortunately it doesn't seem to exist, so you have to implement that class yourself.

Comment: Thank you davyM, 
I will push all my arrays data on the same json url ! it works like a charm. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

DataSeries should solve your problem.  Note that DataSeries was added in dojo 1.5.0.

```
dojo.require("dojox.charting.DataSeries");

chart1.addSeries("Series 1", new dojox.charting.DataSeries(
    test_store, {query: {symbol: "*"}}, "price"));
```

PS I think you should make your follow up question a comment rather than an answer.